# Call observer function when stock inventory attribute updated programatically

Tags: event-observer, performance

I'm updating product stock inventory attribute programactically. Considering performance, instead of saving whole product, I'm saving quantity attribute only.

```
    //  $quantity value
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$mainCurrQty = $stock->getQty();
$stock->setQty($mainCurrQty-$quantity);
```

At the same time I want to call `catalog_product_save_after` observer which is not working as it's not saving the product and saving the attribute value only. How I can call `catalog_product_save_after` observer when only a particular attribute value is updated programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch the event yourself with the same data as Magento does in `save()`:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_after', array(
    'data_object' => $_product,
    'product' => $_product)
);
```

Comment: This is dangerous. If the `$_product` is not fully loaded (it comes form a collection) it may result in loss of data

Comment: I agree that there might be observers that rely on a fully loaded product and don't behave as expected. Loss of data is the worst case, of course, but does not happen per se.

Comment: True. It depends on what the observers for that event do. But it's something that should be kept in mind.